# JNA failure in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, jna

I'm using Cassandra 1.2.3 on Windows, I have downloaded and copied Jna.jar and Platform.jar to  C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-cassandra-1.2.3\lib ,  but when I run Cassandra I get this message

```
INFO 16:20:42,839 JNA link failure, one or more native method will be unavailable.
```

I didn't found any solution to fix it in Windows

Comment: What version of JNA did you download, and what version of JNA is Cassandra expecting?  Likely there's a mismatch, and likely the Cassandra log has a more detailed description of the "JNA link failure", or can emit one if you run with the right options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra does not support JNA on windows.  It only knows how to link libc, which does not exist there.

Comment: It's probably not so much loading libc (you can load msvcrt or the current process, it's pretty much the same thing), but rather the lack of the same memory mapping APIs used on linux.